# How can I add Text to a Picture by a huge List (.txt) and create a Directory for every Picture?

Tags: image, batch-file, imagemagick

At the Moment I have this Script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd "Tools\img\"

convert COMMON2.png -gravity Center -font bold.ttf -pointsize 15 -annotate +45+0 "The Legend of Zelda Breath of the Wild" test.png

xcopy test.png ..\..\

pause
exit
```

My Problem is that the Text is not in the Field where it should be :(

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QOai.png)

and I don't know how to execute this Command with around 3000 different Texts and move them into a new directory for every File. (I would like if all the Files are still called COMMON2.png)

(I saved the Titles into a .txt-File with this Command:

```
@echo off

dir /b "Thumbnails\New\Named_Titles" > NES.txt

pause
```

)

Thanks for every Help that I get ^^

PS: Sorry for my bad English :(

Comment: Welcome as a new user to [SO]. Please take the [Tour] . To get help you should do a bit more than you expect from others, firstly show the effort you put in your code. In scripting very rarely new questions come up. Yours isn't one - maybe you didn't find the right search words.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my Question (completely)

Comment: I don't know what you expect. To fill  an image of size `256px × 64px` with a longer text in a bold font with 15pt sounds impossible. The other thing is you'll need a for loop to iterate the files and create the folders before editing the copy inside the new folder. See [ss64.com/nt/for](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) and it's variants `/F /D /R`

Comment: Okay and how can I get Image Magick to automatically resize the Text and make a Linebreak ?

Comment: By reading the docs and help files like every other programmer does? [SO] isn't a script writing service. [Look at the examples](http://www.google.com/search?q=imagemagick+batch+insert+text+on+image) which are easily to find.

Comment: Where is the text supposed to be?

Comment: @Mark Setchell In the middle of the red (rectangle)(Adobe Illustrator says at 172px 32px)[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/epteq0ubegfj2y4/here.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you an idea how to get started:

```
convert label.png \( -size 150x -background none caption:"The Legend of Zelda Breath of the Wild" -trim \)  -gravity east -geometry +10 -composite result.png
```

[image]

Or maybe this:

```
convert label.png \( -size 150x50 -background none caption:"The Legend of Zelda Breath of the Wild lots more text The Legend of Zelda Breath of the Wild lots more text" -trim \)  -gravity east -geometry +10 -composite result.png
```

[image]

If you are on Windows, you will have to work out the escaping you need - probably change `\(` and `\)` into `(` and `)` or `^(` and `^)`.